# Hidden text not to be Display OR Selected OR Printed in IE, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

HTML :

```
<button id="hide_some_text">Hide</button>
<div id="first">my name is Sea Mist and iam 19 years old</div>
<div id="second" style="display: none">This is the hidden text to be printed and selected only when button is pressed</div>
```

JQUERY :

```
$("#hide_some_text").click(function(){
$("#second").toggle();
});
```

What i want :

If text under div tag "second" is visible only then it should be SELECTED and PRINTABLE
(PLZ note im working in IE) , if text under div tag "second" is hidden then it should not get SELECTED when i do a Ctrl+A -> Ctrl + V and also should not be displayed when i go for Print Preview

Note : im using IE , these problems dont occur in mozzila or chrome , but due to constraints i have to use IE so i need a IE specific solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this in your JavaScript:

```
var cache;
$("#hide_some_text").click(function(){
    if($("#second").is(":visible")) { //if it's not hidden
        cache = $("#second").html(); //cache the HTML
        $("#second").hide().html(""); //hide and empty HTML
    }
    else { //else, it's hidden
        $("#second").show().html(cache); //show and get back HTML
    }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hide_some_text").click();
});
```

Comment: @Aboody , aah i doubt i can do that , actually the text that im printing is pretty complex , throuugh ajax , i cant make ajax call every time i hide and show

Comment: @Aboody , *bows* , that was neat , but one small issue , how do i handle the same if the text in #second is initially hidden using style=display:none, your method works (as a charm) after the button is clicked

Comment: @user1537158 See updated answer. Just remove `style = "display: none;"` initially, then add the `$(document).ready()` part.

Comment: no no i want the text under div tag "second" to be hidden when the web page first loads

Comment: @user1537158 Yes, I know. **Remove** the `style = "display: none;"` first, and add the new `$(document).ready()`. `$("#hide_some_text").click()` simulates clicking the button, so it hides the text.

Comment: @Aboody , that doesnt work , firebug(for debugging im using firefox , ill eventually run on IE) says "TypeError: $("document").ready().$ is not a function"

Comment: @user1537158 What? You have to add this part to your code `$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hide_some_text").click();
});`